# pixel font in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, fonts, pixel

I try pixel fonts from http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/style/Pixel but It's not perfect in the browser and disable anti-aliasing is not an official CSS property (or don't find good sample).

I found this old question : [Is it possible to disable anti-aliasing in CSS when using @font-face with pixel fonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752752/is-it-possible-to-disable-anti-aliasing-in-css-when-using-font-face-with-pixel)

And this JS http://devpro.it/pixelfont/ look very nice but default font is to small (make my own font is not a good deal).
So I would like to know if there is something new or others tips (without swf).

Here is a test with font-face (on webkit, firefox don't ?) : http://b4d455.fr/font/

Answer (score 9):

This might do what you want to some extent:

```
font-smooth: never;
-webkit-font-smoothing : none;
```

Comment: I guess there's no better solution, so you still might want to upvote/accept one of the existing answers.

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm late, but Small Font lets you use this gladly.

#### Here's some working CSS with no links required:

```css
body {font-family: "ＭＳ Ｐゴシック";}
```

```html
<!--- Here's some HTML for the example --->
<h4>Small Font</h4>
<p>Small Font is a pixel font used by Windows when a font is too small to be displayed</p>
<h5>Recommended CSS:</h5>
<code>font-size: 75%;</code>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're asking. But if you're looking to disable anti-aliasing, you might be able to use `-webkit-font-smoothing: none;`.

Comment: I add a test on my post, it's look better without in Chrome and nothing googd in Firefox…