# How to turn off anti-aliasing in text?

Tags: html, css

so for my Sky Web EPG, I want to turn off anti-aliasing on the `<li>` element so that it shows like the original Sky EPG: [Original Sky EPG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yj6KZ.jpg)

Here is how I add the font in the CSS:

```
/* Font Families */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Zurich';
    src: url('Zurich Bold Extended.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'ZurichTV';
    src: url('Zurich Bold Condensed.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Anti Aliasing is off by default you can style it with CSS `li{-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;}`

Comment: :(  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752752/is-it-possible-to-disable-anti-aliasing-in-css-when-using-font-face-with-pixel  have you tryed a `box-shadow:0 0 ;` might help, also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth