# Turn off font smoothing/antialiasing for font-face?

Tags: css, fonts

I try to embed my unusuall font Anonymous Pro to my simple page. The thing is when I define new font-face and use the .ttf file the font looks completely different. When I look closed it seems like the font is now smoehow weirdly smoothed. See:

[up - original, bottom - with font face](https://preview.redd.it/gkxrbadn9ug81.png?width=670&format=png&auto=webp&s=efa41047494503d17db507d6d9d4c0fa79915c18)

The reason I'm doing this is I want to be able to see the original version on devices where Anonymous Pro font is not installed.

I looked [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29684776/1035824) but looks like be Forefox 96 doesn't know such directives.

My question is whats actually going on and how can I fix it?